# Jquery each loop not exiting by return 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

While exiting from `each` loop- `return 0` is not working. However, changing it to `return false` works perfectly.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/codenameavi/gjtr1bvs/)

The regular JavaScript loops (while,for) exits fine by `return 0`. Doesn't it breaks the uniformity!

Comment: @JohnGreen How does that have anything to do with this question?

Comment: Isn't obvious what the difference is? One is a number the other a boolean to start with. An 0 is not false.

Comment: @Vikrant - There's nothing wrong with not understanding the issue.  And yes, return 0 does mean exit a loop. Return *anything* means exit a loop.  $.each is not a loop, per se.

Comment: @JLRishe - The issue is that Jquery is doing an identity check to cancel the $.each.  It is very specifically looking for a return value that is === false.  Since the return value is === 0, it isn't cancelling.  This confuses many programmers, since 0 == false.

Comment: @JohnGreen Ok, I see your point, but this question isn't remotely a _duplicate_ of that one.

Comment: @JLRishe - You're right, although that is the issue, there is another level of indrection going on there.

Comment: @Vikrant, you dint get my point. Sorry that the posted "question text" was so generic. basically the cofusion was- if For & While loops exits/breaks by return 0, why not jQUery "each" !! Doesn't it break the uniformity?

Comment: okay @AviC, I got your point and working on it

Comment: @AviC - The issue is intractable.  Since jQuery's each runs each iteration through a closure, loop statements (break, continue) will never work.  All 'return false' does is simulate a break statement, whereas return [anything else] simulates a continue statement.  This is just the nature of how jQuery has to work within the tools provided by javascript, at least without major tradeoffs in functionality and performance.  The real key is to never try to think of $.each as anything like a for statement.... they're just different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

> We can break the `$.each()` loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return `false`. Returning *non-false* is the same as a `continue` statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

[JSFiddle as example](http://jsfiddle.net/gjtr1bvs/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is simply that `0` is not the exact same thing as `false`.

Usually when a boolean value is required any value will be usable, and it will be converted to a boolean. In that case the `0` would be converted to `false`.

In a jQuery `$.each` loop that wouldn't work. If you don't specifically return anything from a function, then the return value is `undefined`. If that would be converted to a boolean that would also become `false`.

The `$.each` method doesn't convert the return value to a boolean, it specifically looks for the value `false`. Any other value will let the loop continue.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, 0 !== false.

In your own code, you may sometimes check for a false-like answer:

```
0 == false;  // true
null == false;  // true.
```

However, jQuery (rightly so) uses a strict equality (===) operator.

As such:

```
0 === false; // false
null === false;  // false
false === false; // true
```

This if fundamentally an identity vs equality issue:
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

To break a `$.each` loop, you **have** to `return false` in the loop callback.

> Returning anything else skips to the next iteration, equivalent to a
>   `continue` in a normal loop.

[Refer Document](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score -1):

Using return 0, will return zero, which is a number. Using return false says that there is nothing to return, or don't return.

Comment: Using `return false;` doesn't say that there is nothing to return, it returns the value `false`. You might think of `return;` which will return without setting a specific return value, leaving it as `undefined`.

Comment: `return false` means straight away stop the operation in function and Exit

Comment: @Vikrant buddy     `return`     means so, not     `return false`    .  "false" is the value- that the function will return.